# How to thicken a hot chocolate microwave recipe

Tags: chocolate, spicy-hot

I'm trying to perfect the low calorie hot chocolate that is thick as to the point of being almost pudding like or spoonable and easy to make in a microwave.

I'd like to base it on almond milk, cocoa, a stevia-sugar derivate (erythritol or splenda) and a thickening agent.

I've been experimenting with cornstarch, psyllium husks and xanthan and guar gum but haven't yet managed to make the ideal hot chocolate yet.

Any tips or advice how to achieve that consistency?

Comment: Start with a chocolate pudding, then thin it to the point you like, and make a note of how much extra liquid you had to add?  And you'll probably want to add flavorings (ie, not the thickener) as a ratio of how much liquid you added.  Or see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/19332/67

Comment: Hi Sven, and welcome. Exchanging ready-made recipes is off topic here, other sites are much better at that. Asking how to tweak a recipe is right up our alley. So I changed the wording in your question to make it fully on topic. I hope people with the right knowledge about thickeners will soon be able to give you an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with psyllium husks or guar gum, but I do know cornstarch and xanthan gum. [Cornstarch needs be heated to 203 degrees Fahrenheit to have a thickening effect](https://www.exploratorium.edu/cooking/icooks/10-06-03.html), but xanthan gum doesn't. Since you're making it in the microwave, using cornstarch and maintaining that heat may be difficult. I've actually used xanthan gum to thicken hot chocolate before, and I usually use a pinch per cup of milk, but if you want something more puddinglike I might bump it up to 1/2 teaspoon and go from there. Be aware, though, that [too much xanthan gum may cause gas or bloating](https://www.webmd.com/vitamins/ai/ingredientmono-340/xanthan-gum).